# How to pass variables from Job Queue class to Mail view template

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to pass variables from Job Queue class to Mail view template like the following example.

```
 $snippet = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn("snippets","id",$this->details['snippet_id']);

   $snippet_details = [

      'snippet_name'=> $snippet[0]->snippets_name,
      'snippet_image'=> $snippet[0]->snippet_image,
      'snippet_url'=> $snippet[0]->url_slug
   ];

   $subscribers = Constant_model::getDataOneColumn("user_followers","receiver_id",$this->details['published_by']);
   foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){

       $user =User::find($subscriber->sender_id);
       Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Notifynewsnippet($snippet_details));

   }
```

Mail template

```
{{$snippet_details['snippet_name']}}
```

But I am getting the error. please help

Answer (score 0):

You can pass on variablea via view. It is available in the class Mailable:

```
$this->view('mails.hello', ['name' => $name])
```